# How do I pass all command line arguments given to a bash script including string parameters as-is to a child process?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing, posix

The following question is a variation of my problem:

[Bash: Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26067249/1672565)

I want to write a bash script (say 'something.sh') of the following kind ...

```
#!/bin/bash

python $*
```

... which passes all command line arguments as they were given to it directly to the child process. The above based on $* works for commands like ...

```
./something.sh --version
```

... just fine. However, it fails miserably for string arguments like for instance in this case ...

```
./something.sh -c "import os; print(os.name)"
```

... which results (in my example) in ...

```
python -c import
```

... cutting the string argument at the first space (naturally producing a Python syntax error).

I am looking for a generic solution, which can handle multiple arguments and string arguments for arbitrary programs called by the bash script.

Comment: Works fine when I test it?

Comment: Give [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) a try. It automatically points out this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
python "$@"
```

`$@` and `$*` both expand to all the arguments that the script received, but when you use `$@` and put it in double quotes, it automatically re-quotes everything so it works correctly.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters):

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" …`.

See also [Why does $@ work different from most other variables in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310671/why-does-work-different-from-most-other-variables-in-bash/6310889#6310889)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$@`, and quote it.

```
#!/bin/bash

python "$@"
```